# How to handle `npm link` with babel? Getting unexpected token error

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, symlink, npm-link

I am using `npm link` on a parent repo (A) to link a child repo (B).

The `npm link` works like normal but Repo A is using babel to transpile code and seems to either ignore `node_modules` dependencies or symlinks.

I have a spread operator in my Repo B and I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: .../www/adept-him-models/models/event/model.js: Unexpected token (78:10)
  76 |     return full
  77 |       ? {
> 78 |           ...view,
     |           ^
  79 |           // add properties for a full view
  80 |         }
  81 |       : view;
```

Funny thing is that I'm using node version 9.4.0, which should support this natively.

My `package.json`'s dependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "apidoc": "^0.17.6",
    "apidoc-markdown": "^0.2.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^20.0.3",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "dotenv-safe": "^4.0.3",
    "eslint": "^4.4.1",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "jest-cli": "^20.0.4",
    "mockgoose": "^6.0.8",
    "nock": "^9.0.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.10.2",
    "opn-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "sinon": "^4.0.1",
    "supertest": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "adept-him-models": "git+ssh://git@github.com/AdeptMind/adept-him-models.git",
    "async": "^2.6.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "bodymen": "^1.0.3",
    "compression": "^1.7.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.11",
    "mongoose-create-unique": "^0.4.4",
    "mongoose-keywords": "^0.3.2",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "node-random-name": "^1.0.1",
    "querymen": "^2.1.3",
    "random-uri": "^1.0.3",
    "request": "^2.83.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.2"
  }
```

My `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "stage-1"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

Comment: How are you compiling with Babel to begin with?

Comment: That's a good point. I generate the project with https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-rest and invoke `npm run dev` or `npm start`

Answer (score 0):

changing .babelrc to babel.config.json worked for me.